# How to read error code returned from sc.exe command

Tags: powershell

How to read the error code returned from sc.exe in powershell?

I have below code

```
sc.exe create backupService BinPath= $binPath

sc.exe start backupService
```

When executed, below is shown in console which is expected as the service is already running. I want to know how to read the error codes e.g. 1073 or 1056 in powershell for sc.exe output?

```
[SC] CreateService FAILED 1073:

The specified service already exists.

[SC] StartService FAILED 1056:

An instance of the service is already running.
```

Comment: Why not try [New-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=powershell-7.2) and other service management cmdlets instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell sets an Automatic Variable called `$LastExitCode` which contains the exit code of the last external program - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#lastexitcode

Your code would be something like this:

```
sc.exe create backupService BinPath= $binPath
if( $LastExitCode -ne 0 )
{
    # handle error
}

sc.exe start backupService
if( $LastExitCode -ne 0 )
{
    # handle error
}
```